# Is there a very small gap or no gap in this proof? ("Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, dual-spaces

I am reading "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.

Let $V$ be a vector space.
Let $V'$ be the dual space of $V$.
Let $W$ be a vector space.
Let $W'$ be the dual space of $W$.

> Definition:
> If $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$, then the ***dual map*** of $T$ is the linear map $T'\in\mathcal{L}(W',V')$ defined by $T'(\varphi)=\varphi\circ T$ for $\varphi\in W'$.

> Definition:
> For $U\subset V$. The ***annihilator*** of $U$, denoted $U^0$, is defined by $$U^0=\{\varphi\in V' : \varphi(u)=0\text{ for all }u\in U\}.$$

The next result is from "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition". (on p.107)

> **3.108 $T$ surjective is equivalent to $T'$ injective**
> Suppose $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$. Then $T$ is surjective if and only if $T'$ is injective.

> Proof The map $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is surjective if and only if $\operatorname{range} T=W$, which happens if and only if $(\operatorname{range} T)^0=\{0\}$, which happens if and only if $\operatorname{null} T'=\{0\}$ [by 3.107(a)], which happens if and only if $T'$ is injective.

3.107(a) is the following equation:

> If $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$, $$\operatorname{null} T'=(\operatorname{range} T)^0.$$

---

The author is very kind to the readers and, usually, there is no gaps in his proofs in this book.
But I felt a small gap in the proof of 3.108 above.
I felt the following fact is not so obvious.

> Fact 1:
> If $(\operatorname{range} T)^0=\{0\}$, then $\operatorname{range} T=W$.

> Proof:
> Assume that $(\operatorname{range} T)^0=\{0\}$ but $\operatorname{range} T\neq W$.
> Then, $\dim \operatorname{range} T < \dim W$.
> Let $v_1,\dots,v_k$ be a basis of $\operatorname{range} T$.
> Let $v_1,\dots,v_k,\dots,v_l$ be a basis of $W$ ($k<l$).
> Let $\varphi\in W'$ be a linear functional such that
> $\varphi(v_i)=0$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots,l-1\}$ and
> $\varphi(v_l)=1$.
> Then, $\varphi\neq 0$ and $\varphi(v)=0$ for any $v\in\operatorname{range} T$.
> So, $0\neq\varphi\in(\operatorname{range} T)^0$.
> This is a contradiction.

**Does the above fact immediately follow from some famous result?**

By the way, the author commented about 3.107(a) as follows:

> The proof of part (a) of the result below does not use the hypothesis that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.

And in 3.108, the author assumed that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional.
So, we need to use the assumption that $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional in the proof of 3.108.

I guess we need to use the assumption that $W$ is finite-dimensional to prove Fact 1 above.

I guess we don't need the assumption that $V$ is finite-dimensional to prove  3.108.

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry.
I skipped all propositions before 3.108 on p.107 because I just wanted to check the proof of 3.108 while I was watching the author's [lecture video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/JwHnmznnMAc?t=312).

The following result is on p.106:

> 3.106 Suppose $V$ is finite-dimensional and $U$ is a subspace of $V$. Then $$\dim U+\dim U^0=\dim V.$$